# ddply/transform does not apply function to each element of a character vector

Tags: r, dataframe, character, transform, plyr

I have a data frame and I want to transform the first column by using a function that I wrote called "group1":

```
group1 <- function(x) {
  temp <- strsplit(x,"_")[[1]][2]
  temp <- gsub("Yellow", "", temp)
  temp <- gsub("Blue", "", temp)
  as.numeric(temp)
}
```

For instance, applying this function on the string "MHY_Blue23_Yellow16_11A" should yield the result 23. This is indeed what happens when the input is just a string, but when I try to apply this function on a character vector, something goes wrong. I tried to use "transform" to make it work on each element in the vector:

```
data_ling_RT2 <- transform(data_ling_RT, Group1 = group1(Code_Trials)))
```

But instead of getting a data frame with a new column called "Group1" that depends on the respective element in "Code_Trials", I get that all of the elements in "Group1" are based only on the first element of "Code_Trials". I guess this has to do with the way I have written "group1", but I couldn't find what I did wrong.
Using ddply is even worse - sometimes I don't even get anything at all in the column "Group1"...

I would highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are only selecting the first `list` element by using `[[1]]`.  So, when we use the `transform`, the first element that gets modified recycles to the length.

We can change the `group1` function by extracting the element element of each `list` element using `sapply` before doing the `gsub`.  It is not clear why we are replacing the 'Yellow' as the 2nd element seems to have only 'Blue'.

```
 group1 <- function(x) {
   temp <- strsplit(x,"_")
   temp <- sapply(temp, '[', 2) 
   temp <- gsub("Yellow", "", temp)
   temp <- gsub("Blue", "", temp)
   as.numeric(temp)
 }
```

The above code could be simplified to

```
 group2 <- function(x) {
     temp <- strsplit(x,"_")
      temp <- sapply(temp, '[', 2) 
      temp <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', temp))
    }
```

Using a reproducible example

```
 data_ling_RT <- data.frame(Code_Trials= c("MHY_Blue23_Yellow16_11A" , 
       "MHY_Blue24_Yellow16_11A"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 transform(data_ling_RT, Group1 = group1(Code_Trials))
 #              Code_Trials Group1
 #1 MHY_Blue23_Yellow16_11A     23
 #2 MHY_Blue24_Yellow16_11A     24
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun! It worked.
So my fallacy was that I had a list, and ddply and transform are not meant to work on list elements but on data frames. Right? Could I make it work with llply then?

Also, could you please explain the second argument in `sapply(temp,'[', 2)`?
And the first argument in `gsub('\\D+', '', temp)`?

Thank you very much.

PS - the function includes both 'Yellow' and 'Blue', because the input sometimes has 'Blue' and sometimes has 'Yellow' in its second argument.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I didn't know you could use '[' or '[[' as functions in *apply. That was really helpful!